# Python error showing pygame and gymnasium [classic-control] not installed, however both have been

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I have just started learning `OpenAI gymnasium` and started with `CartPole-v1`.
Being new I was following a YouTube tutorial; 
 `video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mut_u40Sqz4&t=2076s` 
(I am up to 1:08:22) and I also wanted to see a window of the game.
However when running the code, Python threw this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gymnasium/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py", line 223, in render
    import pygame ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/artemnikoan/Documents/CartPole-v1.py", line 9, in <module>
    state = env.reset()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gymnasium/wrappers/time_limit.py", line 75, in reset
    return self.env.reset(**kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gymnasium/wrappers/order_enforcing.py", line 61, in reset
    return self.env.reset(**kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gymnasium/wrappers/env_checker.py", line 57, in reset
    return env_reset_passive_checker(self.env, **kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gymnasium/utils/passive_env_checker.py", line 186, in env_reset_passive_checker
    result = env.reset(**kwargs)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gymnasium/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py", line 209, in reset
    self.render()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gymnasium/envs/classic_control/cartpole.py", line 226, in render
    raise DependencyNotInstalled( gymnasium.error.DependencyNotInstalled: pygame is not installed, run `pip install gymnasium[classic-control]`
```

I made sure `pygame` and `gymnasium classic-control` are installed, but it still didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import gymnasium as gym
from stable_baselines3 import PPO
from stable_baselines3.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines3.common.evaluation import evaluate_policy
env=gym.make('CartPole-v1',render_mode='human')
episodes = 5
for episode in range(1, episodes+1):
    state = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0 
    while not done:
        env.render()
        action = env.action_space.sample()
        n_state, reward, done, truncated, info = env.step(action)
        score+=reward
    print('Episode:{} Score:{}'.format(episode, score))
env.close()
log_path=os.path.join('Training', 'Logs')
env = gym.make(environment_name)
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])
model = PPO('MlpPolicy', env, verbose = 1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)
PPO_path = os.path.join('Training', 'Saved Models', 'PPO_model')
model.save(PPO_path)
model = PPO.load(PPO_path, env=env)
evaluate_policy(model, env, n_eval_episodes=10, render=True)
```

I am working on `MAC PC` with using `IDLE`. 
I installed `Pytorch` and every other required module.

What may be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not installed `pygame`. The error message already shows that you have to do: `pip install gymnasium[classic-control]`.

Considering the video provided in OG was from 6th of June 2021, the **Gym** version (not *Gymnasium*) must have been 0.18.3 or lower. The syntax has changed a lot throughout the newer Gym versions, which causes many errors just like you have experienced. One thing for sure, the video provided does not use *Gymnasium*.

I thus also suggest either to downgrade **Gym** to a version <= 0.18.3. I could not find out from the video what version they used, but it must be in aforementioned range. Or, you could make yourself familiar with **Gymnasium** or newer versions of **Gym** to rewrite parts of the code (since Stable Baselines 3 does work with either version).

Might help:

- All Gym versions: https://pypi.org/project/gym/#history
- Gym documentation: https://www.gymlibrary.dev/index.html
- Gymnasium documentation: https://gymnasium.farama.org/

Comment: I just installed gymnasium 0.29.1 and got this error.  Furthermore trying to resolve it in the way recommended in traceback `pip install gymnasium[classic-control]` raises `zsh: no matches found: gymnasium[classic-control]` (pip 23.3.1). Any idea why? Should I raise an issue on their github?

Comment: Found [a discussion about this](https://discord.com/channels/961771112864313344/1126654155268816976/1126660619303665834) on their discord.  You have to run `pip install "gymnasium[classic-control]"` not `pip install gymnasium[classic-control]` as recommended in the traceback. (Mac OS X 14.2 on Intel).

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip install 'gymnasium[classic-control]'` if your using zsh / macOS